# "A fatal error occurred while creating a TLS client credential. The internal error state is 10013." every 10 seconds

Tags: ssl, windows-10

This has been asked before, but I've been through all the answers provided elsewhere so far, i.e. checking permissions on c:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys, adjusting protocols using IISCrypto and turning use of FIPS algorithms on (and off) and I'm still getting batches of 4 events every 10 seconds which swamps the System event log.

I'm running Windows Insider Preview 10 Build 19592.rs_prerelease.200321-1719 (64-bit) so this could be a preview specific issue, however, is there anything else I can try to correct this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer I finally got from a comment on anothersite was that this was a known issue in the Insider Preview and it's now been fixed in the latest releases.

Comment: still have it on 19042.572 20H2 Windows 10 Pro Windows Feature Experience Pack 120.2212.31.0

Comment: I'm still seeing this as well.

Comment: looking for a solution about this Schannel TLS errors. Not sure if it's related to lack or presence of .NET. All suggested hacks in registry has no effect. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/tls#configuring-security-via-the-windows-registry

Answer (score 0):

I've gotten this error on an ASP.NET Core 6.0 service that used to work fine previously.  The problem turned out to be faulty deployment, that removed all files from the virtual directory.